# Can OkHttp cache post responses that have a Authorize in the request header

Tags: android, caching, okhttp

I'm using OkHttp to cache responses to PUT requests that use an "Authorize" header for authentication, and am not seeing any caching.

The Android client code sets the cache like this:

> int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
>
> cache = new Cache(context.getCacheDir(), cacheSize);
>
> client.setCache(cache);

My server is responding with:

> Cache-Control: public, max-age=60, s-maxage=60

When I log the cache, getRequestCount() increments, but there are no hits, or any urls in the cache.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using 2.2? The cache policy changed recently.

Comment: Hi Jesse - yes I'm using 2.2, the latest. It looks like response caching only works for GET, not POST

Comment: Yes. Response caching only works with `GET`.

Answer (score 0):

Only GET responses are cached, so my fix was to convert to GETs. In OkHttp Cache.java:-

```
if (!requestMethod.equals("GET")) {
  // Don't cache non-GET responses. We're technically allowed to cache
  // HEAD requests and some POST requests, but the complexity of doing
  // so is high and the benefit is low.
  return null;
}
```

Comment: sigh.. would it kill them to document it outside code? two days down the drain.